# How can I draw a hyperbola of a complex form

Tags: plotting, complex

How can I use Mathematica to draw locus of point in complex plane given by $||z-i|-|z+i||=1.$
I have tried few codes, but not succeed.

Comment: Replace $z$ with $x+iy$ and use `ContourPlot[]`.

Comment: @J.M.: Aren't there any direct way to draw it?

Comment: Nothing built-in. So, try my suggestion and report back.

Comment: Thank you very much. Definitely I will report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = Abs[z - I] - Abs[z + I] /. z :> x + I y;

Show[

 DensityPlot[f, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  PlotPoints -> 60,
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",
  ImageSize -> 400],

 ContourPlot[{f == 1, -f == 1}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  ContourStyle -> Black,
  ImageSize -> 400]]
```

[image]

Or

```
DensityPlot[f, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
 PlotPoints -> 60,
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",
 ImageSize -> 400,
 Mesh -> {{1}},
 MeshFunctions -> (Function[{x, y}, #] & /@ {f, -f})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This function finds the points that satisfy the complex equation and then plots it.

```
 complexPlot[complexEq_, range_, points_] := Module[{sol, data},

 sol = FindInstance[complexEq && -range < Re[z] < range, z, points];
 data = z /. sol;
 ListPlot[(Tooltip[{Re[#1], Im[#1]}] &) /@ data, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> Full, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", None}, {"x", None}}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Argand diagram"]
 ]
```

You can input your expression as it is in the complex form and specify the x range and number of data points.

```
f = Norm[Norm[z - I] - Norm[z + I]] == 1;
complexPlot[f, 10, 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: I think this solution expends way more effort than this problem warrants.